# How to split each value in a column as a seperate csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a column like this in a csv file:

```
-----
label
-----
0
1
0
2
1
4
3
0
```

Now I need to write each value as a different CSV files that is:

```
0.csv
1.csv
...
7.csv
```

I have tried with the folowing code that can write each line on a single csv file:

```
import re
test_f = open('test.csv')
result_f = open('result.csv', 'a')
for line in test_f:
    new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]'," ", line)
    result_f.write(new_str)

# also, this too, please:
test_f.close()
result_f.close()
```

But I don't know how to save each line in a different file. Any better sugestion, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this code? It already handles the "close" methods for you using context managers (with), skips the header and split the content into files and is splited into functions with separate concerns! ;)

```
import re

def skip_header(source):
    for i in range(3):
        next(source)

def write_file(filename, content):
    print(f'Writting file "{filename}" with content "{content}"...')
    with open(filename, 'w') as destination:
        destination.write(content)

src_filename = './csv/main.csv'
with open(src_filename) as source:
    skip_header(source)
    for index, line in enumerate(source):
        dst_filename = f'./csv/file_{str(index)}.csv'
        content = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]', "", line)
        write_file(dst_filename, content)
```

Here is the folder structure of the simple project. The files **file_X.csv** were generated by the code above (Python 3.6.4).

[image: project folder structure]

Comment: Sorry a naive question, though. What would be the Python 3.3 equivalent of dst_filename = f'./csv/file_{str(index)}.csv'?

Comment: Not a problem, that would be dst_filename = './csv/file_{}.csv'.format(str(index))

Comment: I would recommend you to update your Python installation, but for now, take a look [here](https://pyformat.info/) and check the "new" formats ;)

Comment: Thanks a million, @danieldeveloper001

Comment: Anytime, @Martin :)